# ¿Por que aparecen simbolos raros al crear un excel desde PHP?

Tags: php, excel, codificación

estoy estructurando formatos para instrumentos de medición en PHP para que se descargue en excel mediante esta libreria:

```
  <?php 
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
  officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Muestra.xls");     
  header("Expires: 0"); 
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
  header("Cache-Control: private",false);?>

<table>
   <tr>
     <td><?= utf8_decode("Resolución LO:");?></td>
     <td><?= utf8_decode("λ");?></td>
     <td><?= utf8_encode("λ");?></td>
     <td>λ</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Pero en varios casos requiero que muestre símbolos como "**λ**" o "**α**", pero al ser exportados, Excel los muestra con simbolos extraños o con un simple ?, ya trate de aplicarle un Utf8-encode o decode pero solo muestra otros simbolos. ¿Debo usar una codificación diferente?

Comment: puedes agregar el output del excel que incluye los simbolos??

Comment: puede estar relacionado a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42050930/4717133

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez No, no tienen nada que ver con que todo el documento devuelva cosas rara, solo sucede en las partes donde van los simbolos, por ejemplo muestra cosas como "**ÃŽÂ»**" donde deberia ir el "**λ**"

Comment: ha ok entiendo pero debes agregar tu código que genera el excel si o si

Comment: intentaste usar https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: tambien puedes intentar con `chr()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11830270/4717133

Comment: Ohh entiendo, el codigo es larguisimo, pero puedo sacar una muestra solo para que muestre dicha información

Comment: es lo mínimo que esperamos una muestra reproducible...

Comment: ya se lo que pasa excel no soporta utf-8 automáticamente mira este link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16766198/4717133

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero pude encontrar una manera simple de resolver el problema, ya he publicado una respuesta con una referencia.

Comment: ¿Probaste usar la librería PhpSpreadsheet para generar el Excel?

Answer (score 1):

es verdad, excel no soporta esa codificación para lo que la quiero usar, la respuesta en mi caso fue usar el código html del símbolo "λ" se puede llamar como "& #955;" (todo junto) de esta manera el símbolo se mostro de forma correcta tanto en web como en el exportable de excel.

si alguien mas tiene un problema similar, puede basarse en esta pagina para encontrar el símbolo que desee mostrar:
http://www.webusable.com/CharsExtendedTable.htm